# Count overlapping occurrences of a string in a string

Tags: python, string

I want to count overlapping occurrences of a string in a string.

```
import re
def function(string, sub_string):
    match = re.findall('(?='sub_string')',string)
    return len(match)
```

It shows syntax error:

```
File "solution.py", line 3
    return len(re.findall('(?='sub_string')',string))
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax.
```

But if I write

```
import re
def function(string, sub_string):
    match = re.findall('(?='+sub_string+')',string)
    return len(match)
```

Then its OK. Why I need to include + on both sides?

Comment: `+` is used to concatenate strings.

Comment: If you want to concatenate the close parenthesis at the end of `sub_string` you need to use `+` because that how python understands it.

Comment: this question has nothing to do with regexes, just with how string concatenation works. In short, if you assign a variable, you can append strings to each other without `+`. Within an expression, you need to use `+`. There might be corner cases, But as a rule of thumb, just use `+` and be explicit about what you are doing.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Thanks

Comment: You don't **need** to if you provide an alternative way for string concatenation. You can use, for example, string formatting facilities to keep your pattern as one string: `re.findall(('(?={})'.format(sub_string)), string)`

Answer (score 0):

That is how string concatenation works in Python.

What you are doing here `'(?=' + sub_string + ')'` is, say for example `sub_string = 'hello'`:

`'(?=' + 'hello' + ')'`

Without the concatenation operator, the variable has no place being between two strings.

In Python 3.6, you can use f-strings and simply use one string -which is what I would probably do here:

`f"(?={sub_string})"`